# how to authorize user after storing jwt tokens in the local storage?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, djoser

settings.py

```js
"""
Django settings for auth project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-iogl-doj_#_npx4ss#7mn4!x0zn$gjn!&o7a1=m!u_vf#$_9fi'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
    'authorize',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'auth.urls'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'auth.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authorize.User'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'authdb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING': False,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=2)
}

DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'authorize.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'authorize.serializers.UserSerializer',
    }
}
```

urls.py

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include('authorize.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]
```

authorize/serializers.py

```js
from .models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer, UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer

class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password',
                  'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class UserSerializer(BaseUserSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = authenticate(username=attrs['email'], password=attrs['password'])

        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid email or password")

        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User account is disabled.")

        return user
```

App.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LoginPage.jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function LoginPage() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/jwt/create/', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      });
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
      const token = response.data.token;
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      setError('');
    } catch (error) {
      setError('Invalid email or password');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Even after entering the correct username and password still I cant login. When I go to the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/me/" it says "Unauthorized". Where am I going wrong?
Please help. I have been trying this for 5 hours straight.

Comment: are you able to get a token after logging in?

Comment: yes. Also when I print the axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] in console it gives correct value of the access token. But i dont know why it is not authorizing.
Can you please help me here?

Comment: can you try using Postman and see if your API responding with the status `200`? and share payload after trying.

Comment: and I'm a little confused. what `function LoginPage()` will do? which api function it will call? Can you share rest api which you're trying to call from react?

Comment: @HemalPatel bhai me toh toot gya. Ab nhi hai himmat. Tumse ho jaaye toh batana zarur. Dhanyawaad comment krne ke liye. crying in pain...

Comment: dude :D, Share Repo. will do it

Comment: https://github.com/vansh2002/Auth. Bhaiya aapke sahare hi hai mera aaj ka din poora. Thanks in advance

Comment: @HemalPatel LoginPage() posts username and password to the "/token/" endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252983/discussion-between-hemal-patel-and-vansh-chaudhary).

Answer (score 0):

use
`` `Token ${token}`; ``
this instead
`Bearer ${token}`;

Comment: localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access);
      const token = response.data.access;
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
I made these changes but doesn't do any good